# Button to Clear text with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript

I'm using Bootstrap to generate tabs.  I have a reset button which clears the content from the tab but it doesn't work.  Here's my code:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <?php echo "Some text" ?>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="document.nav-tabContent.nav-home.value=''">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

So my "Clear" button should clear the text, "Some text".  How would go about in clearing the text with the button??

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrap `<?php echo 'some text'; ?>` in for example a `<p>` tag and add this code to the onlick event in button tag

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = '';">Clear</button>
```

Try this live example having many tabs

```js
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')
const tabPanes = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane');

navItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', clear));

function clear(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const element = event.target;
    const paneId = element.getAttribute('href').split('#')[1];
    const pane = document.querySelector(`#${paneId}`);

    clearNavItems();
    clearPanes();

    element.classList.add('active');

    pane.classList.add('show');
    pane.classList.add('active');
}

function clearNavItems() {
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
}

function clearPanes() {
    tabPanes.forEach(pane => {
        pane.classList.remove('active');
        pane.classList.remove('show');
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus qui, pariatur ipsum ducimus numquam porro optio adipisci, nemo, cupiditate unde mollitia accusantium, suscipit. Explicabo, officiis corrupti praesentium. Quis, unde, fugit.</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = '';">Clear</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto.</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = '';">Clear</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa mollitia unde perspiciatis?</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = '';">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the quick response.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to add some id or class at your "Some Text" php, like

```
<span id="abc"><?php echo "Some Text"; ?></span>
```

So you can access it with jquery or javascript like this onclick button

```
onclick="somefunction()"
```

And

```
somefunction() {
  $('#abc').html("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by what you currently have, I would make the following edit:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
    <p id="nav-home-text"><?php echo "Some text" ?></p>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="document.getElementById('nav-home-text').innerHTML=''">Clear</button>
</div>
```

1. Targeting to clear `nav-home` will also clear he `button` as the `button` is part of `nav-home`
2. Wrap the text in a `<p>` and give it an `id` so you could target it from the button using `document.getElementById()`
3. You should only target `.value` for elements that have the `value` attribute `e.g` `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some jquery to remove the text.

first you need to place the text inside the **span** with the id **content** and clear the text inside the content using jquery.

you can use this.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <span id="content"><?php echo "Some text" ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#content').text('');">Clear</button>
</div>
```